# Accessing variables in another function without the variable being in the function parameter

Tags: c

```
void foo() {
    int i = 3;
    bar();
}

void bar() {
    //print i in foo()
}
```

I was wondering if there is some way that I could do this without setting a global variable?

Comment: There isn't, but more importantly, why would you need to do that?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Without any address or value of what you want to display it's not possible.

Comment: Trying to get around a restriction for the partitioning step of quicksort whereby the partition function can't have parameters of low and high that is used for the partitioning step. I wanted to create a stack that stored the indexes of low and high and pass it into the partition function.

Comment: Why can't it!? Is this a homework restriction?

Comment: Yes it is, and I am completely stumped on how to do it

Comment: I can't say without seeing your homework, but I daresay you only need the value of the pivot in the partition step. You should be able to calculate it beforehand, in a separate step.

Comment: But how would I know when to stop partitioning the sub arrays since there is no index?

Comment: I think you are missing something crucial. An array in C is a contiguous block of memory, which is identified by the address of its first element. So if your array is `1, 2, 3, 4 ,5`, you could pass the address of `4` to a function (along with an adjusted size), and it would think it is looking at an array `4, 5`. That is the whole recursive nature of quick sort.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic! That did not cross my mind at all thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73534/discussion-between-user3529361-and-storyteller).

Comment: If you can pass a parameter, then pass a parameter called `stuff` that is a pointer to a structure containing everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is a local variable and is stored in the stack for that method, outside that method the stack does not exist and can not be read

Comment: Maybe it's implementation dependant but i can read the stack from any function based on an address of a local variable. I'm using gcc on Debian and i can read the address of the `i` variable from inside the `bar` function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just use the value of `i`, you can use:

```
void bar(int i);

void foo() {
    int i = 3;
    bar(i);
}

void bar(int i) {
    //print i in foo()
}
```

If you want to be able modify the value of `i`, use:

```
void bar(int* ip);

void foo() {
    int i = 3;
    bar(&i);
}

void bar(int* ip) {
   *ip = 20;
}
```

Comment: I guess `void bar(int*)` is what OP looking for.

Answer (score 1):

C uses static scoping. You can check this here: https://msujaws.wordpress.com/2011/05/03/static-vs-dynamic-scoping/ :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass `i` from `foo` to `bar` as parameter:

```
bar(i);

void bar(int i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you have to pass it to `foo` as an argument. The reason for this is that when a C function is called it creates any local variables defined inside it on the stack, which is essentially just a form of dynamic memory allocation. When the function returns, it frees the memory used by those variable. Now you might think there should be some way for `bar` to know about `i` since it is still present on the stack when `bar` is called inside `foo`. But the problem is that C does not make any assumptions about who might be calling the `bar` function. You could just as easily call `bar` from a third function that has no `i` defined within it. For this reason there is no mechanism for accessing stack variables from a nested function without passing them explicitly.

Interestingly, having the ability to do this built into the language is one of the key features that allows for the implementation of closures. So if you have ever struggled to understand what made these so special, this is basically it. Probably not as spectacular as the hype might have lead you to believe.